# AI predict in Tensorflow with a "mean" of a embedded feature

Tags: tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, feature-extraction, feature-selection

Example: I have a tensorflow model which predicts house prices. I have a hash bucket feature for city:

```
tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('city', hash_bucket_size=1000, dtype=tf.string)
```

But when I predict I also want to be able to predict with a "general" city. Sort like a "mean" of all cities.

So I get a house price not dependent of which city the house is in.

Is this possible?